# View with two positions using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a list of views that I want to position. I have two states where the views should be positioned differently.

I am new to AutoLayout and I might be accessing this the wrong way - I am open to different ways of doing this.

I have created this to position a list of `TabBarItem : UIView` for the first state:

```
NSMutableDictionary* metrics = [@{@"margin": @(TAB_BAR_ITEM_MARGIN)} mutableCopy];

for (int i = 0; i < [self.tabBarItems count]; i++)
{
    TabBarItem* item = [self.tabBarItems objectAtIndex:i];

    if (i > 0)
    {
        TabBarItem* lastAddedItem = [self.tabBarItems objectAtIndex:i - 1];
        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(item, lastAddedItem);
        NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[item]-(==margin)-[lastAddedItem]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary];
        [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(item);
        NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(>=0)-[item]-(==margin)-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary];
        [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
    }

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(item);
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(==0)-[item]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

`self.view` is the `superview` of the `TabBarItem`s.

Now I want to be able to move all the `TabBarItem`s to completely different position (will probably require different constraints) using AutoLayout.

How should I approach this? Can I identify a constraint and remove it to add another?

As mentioned I am new to AutoLayout and really want to do this the right way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by having two `NSMutableArray`s: One for all the constraints needed in the first position and one for all the constraints needed in the other position. By doing that I was able to remove the active constraints from the first list and then add the new ones from the second list.

Not very elegant, but I couldn't find another way to do it.